# file_get_contents не работает, помогите разобраться

Tags: php

```
index.php

<?php
$mytitle = "Мой заголовок";
$mybody = "Моя страница";
$block0 = file_get_contents('top.htm')
echo $block0;
?>

top.html

<html><head><title> $mytitle </title></head>
<body> $mybody </body></html>
```

Прошу прощения за банальщину, почему не работает? Что корректнеее использовать в данном случае вместе file_get_contest?

Comment: чего бы просто include не сделать ?

Comment: если не сложно кусочек кода

Comment: Я совсем чуточку экстросенс, что конкретно не работает, не подключается файл или все же ожидаемый результат, т.е. переменные отображаются как `$mytitle` и `$mybody`?

Comment: файл подключается, не заменяются переменные.

Comment: Смотрите ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php

```
$title = 'My Title';
$body = 'Body Content';

$top = file_get_contents('top.html');

$top = str_replace
(
    array
    (
        '$title',
        '$body',
    ),

    array
    (
        $title,
        $body
    ),

    $top
);

echo $top;
```

top.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> $title </title>
    </head>
    <body> $body </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Дорогие гуру спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mytitle = "Мой заголовок";
$mybody = "Моя страница";
ob_start();
include 'top.html';
$block0 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: спасибо хороший вариант, не сильно ли напряжет сервер если  таких Ob_start будет несколько?

Comment: Нет, не напряжет.